# How to make div height fit the content using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a website and there is a list of item which displayed like this:

[image]

```
<?php foreach($category->getHighlightedProject() as $project):?>
    <div class="portfolio-project">
        <?php 
            $photo = $project->getTopMostPhoto($project->project_id);
            if ($photo):
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl."/".Yii::app()->params['uploadPath']."/".Yii::app()->params['project']['uploadPath']."/".$photo->getPhotoNameWithSize($photo->project_photo_image_file_name, ProjectPhoto::SIZE_MEDIUM);?>" alt="<?php echo $project->project_name;?>"/>
        <div class="portfolio-desc">
            <div class="portfolio-desc-title"><?php echo $project->project_name;?></div>
            <div class="portfolio-desc-short-desc"><?php echo $project->project_short_desc;?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

If an item is hovered, .portfolio-desc will pop up, but still inside .portfolio-project.

Here is the css:

```
.portfolio-highlight {margin-top: 30px; text-align: center;}
.portfolio-item {width: 25%; float: left;}
.portfolio-category {margin-bottom: 30px;}
.portfolio-category a{font-size: 16px; font-family: 'ralewaybold';}
.portfolio-project {height: auto; position: relative; overflow:auto;}
.portfolio-project img {max-width: 100%;}
.portfolio-desc {display: none; width: 90%; height: 80px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; background: url('../img/portfolio-desc-bg.png') repeat 0 0; color: #FFF; padding: 5%; line-height: 2.0em;}
.portfolio-desc-title {font-size: 16px; font-family: 'ralewayextrabold';}
.portfolio-desc-short-desc {font-size: 13px;}
```

The problem is, .portfolio-project doesn't seem to fit width the content's height. Noticed there is a white line below the first line of items. They are extra spaces of .portfolio-project.

What did I do wrong? I've been looking for solutions for days and still haven't found a clue. Can anybody help? Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that is has to do with a line that is added by putting an image inside a div :

[Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5804256/3168107)

One solution I made a demo for (before I found that topic) is using `line-height: 0` on the parent :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VveXJJ?editors=110

```
.portfolio-project {
line-height: 0;
}
```